# Requirements for uploading to App Store - Business App

Tags: ios, xcode, submission

I have been thinking about submitting an app for my company, and it would serve as a simple app to get contact information easily.

But the question is, how much info to I actually need in the app to get it through the gates of appstore?

Currently the app is including:
- Different companies within our organization
- Small infotext about each
- Email button
- Phone button
- Contact persons, which leads to another view where I have contact persons with pictures, names, and direct phone/email buttons

Is this enough or do I need to include more features?

Comment: yes, that is enough.

Comment: The only way you can find out is to submit it.  From your description, however, it seems likely it would be rejected.  What does your app do that a simple web site couldn't? See https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality

Comment: Well, it does pretty much the same as a website, only more accsessible from a phone.

Comment: Wouldn't a website with a responsive design achieve the same thing?

Comment: Most of the things would be the same yes. But I feel if you can have 3 taps within the app to call a specific person, rather than looking it up on the web it would be faster.

I also considered Push notification, to push out spesific Deals or discounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even add a app with single feature which is useful for the apple users, The only thing is make sure your app doesn't violet any of the app review guidelines and while preparing your app for submission on App store, in meta data information specifically mention that your app is for your orgnization's personal use

You will find apple app review guideline at following URL:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/